# Difficulty with CSS background divider

Tags: html, css

I have made a basic navigation bar with four 'buttons' and I am using a background image as a divider. The problem I am having is when I create a :hover state, the background covers up the divider. How can I fix this so that the divider image always shows?

Here is the markup:

```
<div>                                                 
<ul class="main">                                
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="divl" href="#">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a class="divl" href="#">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a class="divl" href="#">Item3</a></li>
</ul>                                            
</div>
```

---

```
ul.main {

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
width: 1000px;
background: url(grad.png) repeat-x; 
overflow: hidden;}

ul.main li{

float: left;}

ul.main a {
padding: 0 3em;
line-height: 3em;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
color: white;}

.divl {

background: url(a.png) repeat-y top left;}

ul.main a:hover, 
ul.main a:focus{

background: rgba(0,200,0,0.1);}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is the divider image supposed to show between the LIs? If so, then you need to make space between the LIs...margin will work.

Comment: Id use border instead: you could use a `border-right` and/or `border-left` if you don't want it to show the whole box. Actually, I'm pretty sure, you can use an image as a border with `border-image`, although I don't know how well its implemented on browsers. hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the divider `background-image` to the `li` elements instead:

```
ul.main li {
    float: left;
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/1x100/f0f/fff) repeat-y top right;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/825cK/

Answer (score 0):

How about you take the divider outside of the background image and place a div inside the list item? Then you can style the divider as you like without the :hover background getting in the way.

Something like:

```
<li><a href="#">link here</a><div class="divider"></div></li>
```

-or-

Put the divider in the list item as a background.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have a more fundamental problem with the overall structure of your backgrounds.  If the user magnifies the text on their browser, the text will overlap with your borders on your background image no matter what way you spin it.

It's hard because I can't see what the background is supposed to be, but if your background just a vertical linear gradient, you would probably be better off slicing it up and making it as a single background for each List Item instead of the entire Unordered List.

This will allow you the flexibility to fix the problem you initially posted with use of margins, and also make your job much easier if you ever need to add another 'button.'