# CSS Background Divider

Tags: html, css, background, transform, divider

I found the following CSS Background Divider: [Difficulty with CSS background divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558910/difficulty-with-css-background-divider) . But I would like to horizontally flip the diagonal line. So the higher part is on the left, and the lower part on the right. I tried to change the transform degrees, but somehow it doesn't work out.

Do you know how to fix this?

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0px;
}
p {
    color: white;
}
section {
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
section:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
}
section.diagonal {
    background: blue;
}
footer {
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
footer:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
}
footer.diagonal {
    background: black;
}
.diagonal {
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 3em;
}
.diagonal:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 3% 0;
    transform-origin: 3% 0;
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 150%;
    height: 75%;
    background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <p>Header</p>
</header>
<section class="diagonal">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</section>
<footer class="diagonal">
    <p>Footer</p>    
</footer>
```